# How to clear/empty pasteboard on viewWillDisappear

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview, uipasteboard

I use `UIPasteboard` to copy/paste text between two `UITextView`.

Code looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]; //it is declared in .h as UIPasteboard *pasteBoard;
}

-(IBAction)doCopyBtn {
    if (![toCopyTextView.text isEqualToString:@""]){
        pasteBoard.string = toCopyTextView.text;
        NSLog(@"pasteb1 %@", pasteBoard.string);
    } else {
        NSLog (@"error! enter smth");
    }
}

-(IBAction)doPasteBtn {
    if (![pasteBoard.string isEqualToString:@""]){ 
        toPasteTextView.text = pasteBoard.string;
        NSLog(@"pasteb2 %@", pasteBoard.string);
    } else {
        NSLog (@"error! enter smth");
    }
}
```

And even this cant help  (NSLog returns: `pasteb2 (null)`)

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [pasteBoard setString:@""]; 
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## iOS – `UIPasteboard`

Try the following:

```
    UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    [pb setValue:@"" forPasteboardType:UIPasteboardNameGeneral];
```

Arab_Geek's response is correct but available for Cocoa (and I suspect you are looking for an iOS solution)

Comment: Thanks for answer. If someone wants an ugly long single line: `[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setValue:@"" forPasteboardType:UIPasteboardNameGeneral];`

Answer (score 3):

## OS X - `NSPasteboard`

Here you go ..

```
NSPasteboard *pb = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pb declareTypes: [NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType] owner: self];
[pb setString: @"" forType: NSStringPboardType];
```

Comment: unfortunately it misunderstands "NSStringPboardType". Also, NSPasteboard doesn't exists.

Comment: @Sheonna8 #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h> <- add this to your .m file

Comment: trued, writes <Cocoa/Cocoa.h> not found (I also tried to find framework - unsuccessful)

Answer (score 2):

Setting the value to `""` will return `nil` for all intended purposes. It will, however, leave the pasteboard in a slightly different state as before a paste operation.

**Swift**

```
let pb = self.pasteBoard()
pb.setValue("", forPasteboardType: UIPasteboardNameGeneral)
```

...is not equivalent to `UIPasteboard.removePasteboardWithName()`. If restoring the `UIPasteboard` state is of concern(1), you can use the following block:

**Swift**

```
let pb = self.pasteBoard()

let items:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: pb.items)
for object in pb.items {
    if let aDictionary = object as? NSDictionary {
        items.removeObject(aDictionary)
    }
}
pb.items = items as [AnyObject]
```

*(1) Restoring state.*