# Clear UIPasteBoard

Tags: swift, uipasteboard

Lets assume that 3 strings have been copied on the UIPasteBoard:

```
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string="hello"
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string="world"
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string="!"
```

I use 
    UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string=""

Will it clear the pasteboard? Is there any similar func for UIPasteBoard like there is clearContents()  for NSPasteBoard?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11211203

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you know that your program is the only one manipulating the specific  pasteboard, then yes, setting the `string` property to `""` will effectively clear the pasteboard.

You can easily test this in Playground

```
var pb = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
pb.string = "hello"
pb.string
pb.items
pb.string = ""
pb.string   
pb.items
```

which outputs

```
<UIPasteboard: 0x7fed6bd0a750>
<UIPasteboard: 0x7fed6bd0a750>
"hello"
[["public.utf8-plain-text": "hello"]]
<UIPasteboard: 0x7fed6bd0a750>
nil
[[:]]
```

However, note that `string` property of UIPasteboard is a shorthand for the first pasteboard item that is of type string. All items of type string can be accessed through `strings` property.

All underlying pasteboard items are modelled in `items` property, which is an array of dictionaries of type `[String: AnyObject]`. Each dictionary contains the type information of an object in the key and pasteboard value in the value.

Because you are using a system-wide `generalPasteboard`, it can also be manipulated by other programs, thus, to clear all items from the pasteboard, you should use

```
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().items = []
```

If you are using the pasteboard for your internal application purposes, it is better to create an internal pasteboard than to use a system-wide generalPasteboard. See [`pasteboardWithUniqueName()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIPasteboard/pasteboardWithUniqueName)

Comment: Thank you Teemu. generalPasteboard is what i need, so other apps will use it as well but i am only interested for strings to be cleared from the pasteboard.Are you saying that my solution will clear all the strings stored but not Ints or images? While the solution you propose will clear everything?

Comment: No, your solution will clear only the first pasteboard string item. If you want to clear all strings, you can try `pb.strings = []`.

Comment: This solution will clear the `UIPasteboard.general.strings`.  Try it in the playground ```swift
import UIKit
UIPasteboard.general.strings = ["this", "is", "a", "test"]
print("UIPasteboard.general.strings:",
      UIPasteboard.general.strings?.description ?? "empty")
print("UIPasteboard.general.string:",
      UIPasteboard.general.string?.description ?? "blank")
UIPasteboard.general.items = []
print(UIPasteboard.general.strings?.description ?? "empty")
```