# Clearing clipboard in ios 9.3 doesn't work

Tags: ios, uikit

I have the following code snippet for clearing user's clipboard:

```
func clearClipboard() {

    let pb = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
    let pbtypes = pb.pasteboardTypes()

    for pbtype in pbtypes {
        pb.setValue("", forPasteboardType: pbtype)
    }

    print("Clipboard was cleared")
}
```

I tested the code on iPhone running iOS 8.4 and it works. However, on iOS 9.3 it doesn't work. On iOS 9.3, the `pbtypes` array is empty.

Did Apple change anything in the API permissions? Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after more investigation it looks like this the way to clear the clipboard:

```
pb.setValue("", forPasteboardType: UIPasteboardNameGeneral)
```

Credit to this thread: [How to clear/empty pasteboard on viewWillDisappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067554/how-to-clear-empty-pasteboard-on-viewwilldisappear)